# Getting error while adding custom service in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I'm new in AngularJS and i have setup everything in angular js but when i'm going add new authentication service then i'm getting error like this:

[image]

I have create service called **sessionService.js** for set and get user value in session
I have create service called **authService.js** for checking user authentication and get username and it etc

Here is **sessionService.js**

```
'usre strict';

app.factory('sessionService', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        set : function(key,value){
            return sessionStorage.setItem(key,value);
        },
        get : function(key){
            return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
        },
        destroy : function(key){
            return sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
        }
    }
}])
```

Here is **authService.js**

```
'use strict';

app.factory('authService', ['$http','sessionService', function($http,sessionService){
      var loggedIn;
    var isAdmin;
    var username;
    var id;

    var checkLogin = function() {
        // Create a custom deferred
        var defer = $q.defer();

        if(loggedIn != undefined) {
            // Resolve your deferred with the value of logged in
            defer.resolve(loggedIn);
        } else {
            setUserData().then(function (data) {
               loggedIn = data.logged;
               if(loggedIn) {
                  isAdmin = data.is_admin;
                  username = data.username;
                  id = data.id;
                  defer.resolve(loggedIn);
               } else {
                  defer.reject();
               }
            }, function () {
               defer.reject();
            });
        }

        return defer.promise;
    }

    var returnUsername = function() {
        // Create a custom deferred
        var defer = $q.defer();

        if(username != undefined) {
            // Resolve your deferred with the value of logged in
            defer.resolve(username);
        } else {
            setUserData().then(function (data) {
               loggedIn = data.logged;
               if(loggedIn) {
                  username = data.username;
                  defer.resolve(username);
               } else {
                  defer.reject();
               }
            }, function () {
               defer.reject();
            });
        }

        return defer.promise;
    }

    var returnId = function() {
        // Create a custom deferred
        var defer = $q.defer();

        if(id != undefined) {
            // Resolve your deferred with the value of logged in
            defer.resolve(id);
        } else {
            setUserData().then(function (data) {
               loggedIn = data.logged;
               if(loggedIn) {
                  id = data.id;
                  defer.resolve(id);
               } else {
                  defer.reject();
               }
            }, function () {
               defer.reject();
            });
        }

        return defer.promise;
    }

    var setUserData = function(callback) {
        return $http.get('/api/checkLogin');
    }

    return {
        loggedIn: function() { return checkLogin(); },
        username: function() { return returnUsername(); },
        id: function() { return returnId(); },
    }
}])
```

I have added this both service in index.html also

```
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/config.js"></script>
  <script src="js/config.lazyload.js"></script>
  <script src="js/config.router.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services/ui-load.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services/sessionService.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services/authService.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters/fromNow.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/setnganimate.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/ui-butterbar.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/ui-focus.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/ui-fullscreen.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/ui-jq.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/ui-module.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/ui-nav.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/ui-scroll.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/ui-shift.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/ui-toggleclass.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

And in **app.js**

```
'use strict';


angular.module('app', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngStorage',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.utils',
    'ui.load',
    'sessionService',
    'authService',
    'ui.jq',
    'oc.lazyLoad',
    'pascalprecht.translate',
]);
```

I need help for solving this issue.
I'm using Angular Bootstrap Admin panel for it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: is it  Failed to instantiate module error ?

Comment: Yes that's what is display in error but i'm not getting it so

Comment: You are not adding reference for `angular.js`

Comment: `app.factory` ? what is stored your app variable ? make sure u have `var app = angular.module('app')`

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are treating `sessionService` and `authService` as a module and loading them as dependency in your `app`. They are services and not the modules. Even the error says the same. The services can be injected in other services but cannot be loaded as module dependencies.

Change your code in `app.js` to remove the services as below:

```
'use strict';


var app = angular.module('app', [
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngAria',
  'ngCookies',
  'ngMessages',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngTouch',
  'ngStorage',
  'ui.router',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'ui.utils',
  'ui.load',
  'ui.jq',
  'oc.lazyLoad',
  'pascalprecht.translate',
]);
```

Comment: Yes i have done this but now it display like this error : **Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: authService**

Comment: This error means that there is some syntax error in your `authService` code. Can you recheck that or create a plunkr with your complete code?

Comment: Ok. The issue is that you are trying to access global variable app, when it is not defined. I have updated the app.js code.

Answer (score 0):

Include your app.js script after all others.

Comment: not working its give me other error not found of other module so i cant add  it at last

Answer (score 0):

Is your app was instantiated globally to be used in other js files. Let's say

App.js

```
var app = angular.module('app',[dependencies]);
$(function(){
//Other code
}());
```

And using instantiated app in other js files.